# Lost files after 'fix' for missing Unity menus

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher, compiz

I ran Bleachbit to clean up my 16.04 system (which I've done before with no problems). After reboot the Unity launcher and top menu were missing but I could see my desktop and files. I right clicked and I tried in the Terminal:

- Starting Unity
- Reinstalling Unity
- Purging & reinstalling Unity
- Installing CCSM & enabling Unity

... all with no luck restoring the launcher or top menu.

I then tried:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ setsid unity
```

... but nothing happened.

I then tried:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
```

... and after a reboot a 'factory clean' install of Unity appeared and all my applications, files and folders had disappeared. Help!!!

Is there a way to restore or retrieve my files?

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -A ~`

Comment: Whoops, I meant `ls -A1 ~`

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that all that has disappeared is symlinks and desktop files, not actual applications and data files. I don't know much about Compiz or Unity, but I suspect you could go to /usr/share/applications and copy the desktop files you want to be able to launch from icons on your desktop to /home/your-user-name/Desktop/

For direct access to directories (aka "folders") from your desktop, you can make new symlinks and put them in /home/your-user-name/Desktop/

For each such directory:

```
ln --symbolic -T /actual/path/to/directory /home/your-user-name/Desktop/whatever-you-want-to-call-the-link
```

Probably you deleted something that tells compiz to put those things there, so try putting them there yourself.

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling compiz.

In the future, NEVER delete any kind of config file without making a backup copy.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to see the programs in the directory that you suggested :) However, I cannot see any of my files and documents in the GUI. Do you know where in the system files, or elsewhere, these might also be accessible?

Comment: Assuming I am right about the nature of the problem, they should be where you saved them to begin with. Try looking in /home/your-user-name/ and /home/your-user-name/documents.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen. These 2 commands worked for me:

```
mv ~/.cache/compizconfig-1 ~/.cache/compizconfig-OLD
setsid unity
```

Hope it helps.